# Why is max_size called twice in C++ allocator?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, allocator

I was playing around with allocators and I discovered that `max_size` is called twice each time for `vector`. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
class static_allocator
{
   public:
    using size_type = size_t;
    using difference_type = ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T*;
    using const_pointer = const T*;
    using reference = T&;
    using const_reference = const T&;
    using value_type = T;

    static_allocator() {}
    ~static_allocator() {}

    template <class U>
    struct rebind { typedef static_allocator<U> other; };
    template <class U>
    static_allocator(const static_allocator<U>&) {
    }

    pointer address(reference x) const { return &x; }
    const_pointer address(const_reference x) const { return &x; }
    size_type max_size() const throw()
    {
        size_type max = (size_type)(-1) / sizeof(T);
        std::cout << "  max_size " << max << std::endl;
        return max ;
    }

    pointer allocate(size_type n,
                     const_pointer hint = 0)
    {
        std::cout << "  allocate " << n << std::endl;
        return static_cast<pointer>(malloc(n * sizeof(T)));
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) {
        std::cout << "  deallocate " << n << std::endl;
        free(p); }

    void construct(pointer p, const T& val)
    {
        std::cout << "  construct " << val << " for "  << typeid(p).name() << std::endl;
        new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T(val);
    }

    void construct(pointer p) {
        std::cout << "  construct" << typeid(p).name() << std::endl;
        new (static_cast<void*>(p)) T();
    }

    void destroy(pointer p) {
        std::cout << "  destroy " << typeid(p).name() << std::endl;
        p->~T(); }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int, static_allocator<int>> v;
    std::cout << "START" << std::endl;
    for (auto i : std::array<int, 7>{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42, 108}) {
        std::cout << "push_back " << i << std::endl;
        v.push_back(i);
    }
    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
START
push_back 4
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  allocate 1
  construct 4 for Pi
push_back 8
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  allocate 2
  construct 8 for Pi
  construct 4 for Pi
  destroy Pi
  deallocate 1
push_back 15
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  allocate 4
  construct 15 for Pi
  construct 4 for Pi
  construct 8 for Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  deallocate 2
push_back 16
  construct 16 for Pi
push_back 23
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  max_size 4611686018427387903
  allocate 8
  construct 23 for Pi
  construct 4 for Pi
  construct 8 for Pi
  construct 15 for Pi
  construct 16 for Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  deallocate 4
push_back 42
  construct 42 for Pi
push_back 108
  construct 108 for Pi
END
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  destroy Pi
  deallocate 8
```

Comment: Why not? The vector is allowed to call `max_size()` as many times as it likes.

Comment: Which implementation of the C++ standard library?

Comment: @DanielLangr I don't know. glibc on Ubuntu 20.04? How can I check?

Comment: @RaymondChen Indeed, but it is not quite efficient to call it twice in a row...

Comment: The expectation is that it is very fast (just returns a constant or maybe a member variable), so a second call is basically free. Example: [`if (__size > max_size() || __navail > max_size() - __size)`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/936d40b9ba9cdf8571bc5c366f3d3237cabc30c2/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/vector.tcc#L635)

Comment: @nowox Then, it's likely libstdc++. You can check the source code here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h. Look for `max_size`.

Comment: Note that the C++17 way of implementing `max_size` is through `std::allocator_traits`, and the default implementation is `constexpr` since C+20. In short, it's expected that `max_size` just returns a constant and doesn't print anything.

Comment: @RaymondChen you're not from the embedded world then :) Programming for wearable devices with batteries that should last at least 10 years, you could every single line of code...

Comment: @nowox an inlined function call especially if it's `constexpr` should have no extra cost even if its on an embedded platform